# Documentation about the compressed AndroidManifest.xml file format

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest, reverse-engineering, aapt

I am looking for information about how the AndroidManifest.xml is encoded within an apk file.

In fact, this file is compressed in a specific format by aapt before being stored in the apk file.

I could try to reverse the format by looking into aapt source code, but maybe there is already some documentation around.

Thanks

Comment: I'm interested in this too since I have a side project going to write a 'decompiler', for lack of a better term.  Only documentation I have seen is with the various projects that have implemented a similar en/decoding.

Answer (score 1):

It's Android binary XML. For what it's worth, resource XML files are also compiled to this binary form before packaging to the APK.

To decode it, you can use the [axml](https://code.google.com/p/axml/) library.